# Seperate the base file name from the extension

Tags: regex, perl

(Note: Not necessarily must use regex)
For example my string is

```
my $str = "namefile.json.bz2"
```

I want the main file name only which is `namefile`

The regex that i tried is `^([^?=\b(.bz2)\b]*)`
This works if my string (the file name does not contain b,z or 2.

If `my $str = "bigzoom.jzon.bz2"` It will fail considering it found character 'b'.
Is there better regex to match exactly `.bz2` ?

For reference: https://regex101.com/r/oRvMVL/1

Edit: The extension list are many. So the regex must match all those extension (in OR format) For example `^([^?=\b(.bz2)\b | \b(.json)\b | \b(.txt)\b | \b(.log)\b]*)` I could later on update more extension if needed. But that's the concern. To get the filename without any extension.

Comment: What are your exact matches, and can you show more sample data?

Comment: With `"namefile.json.bz2"` as the input you say *I want the main file name only which is `namefile`*, but later on you say *Is there better regex to match exactly `.bz2`*. Which is it? What are your conditions of matching exactly? It it you want to match the first part of the filename only if the last part is "bz2"?

Comment: I've edited the question to clarify the issue.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to take the "main" part of the file name that is not an extension, use this simple regex.

```perl
# Grab everything up to the first dot character
(my $mainname) = $filename =~ m/^([^.])+/;
```

If you want to strip a known file extension, just use this.

```perl
# Remove this exact string.
$filename =~ s/\.json\.bz2$//i;
```

For the official way to do it, see the [File::Basename](https://perldoc.perl.org/File::Basename) module.

```
use File::Basename;

print fileparse("/foo/bar/name.json.bz2", qr/\..*/);

# ---
# ("name", "/foo/bar/", ".json.bz2")

# or
print fileparse("/foo/bar/name.json.bz2", qr/\.[^.]*/);

# ---
# ("name.json", "/foo/bar/", ".bz2")
```

Comment: The extension format here not limited to those two. I need to create regex that could match other extension also. For example ```.log``` , ```.gz2``` , ```.txt``` So the concern now is I cannot use your first method cause I do not want to limit if the filename could contain any dot (.) character. filename.abc.json.bz2 or it could be filename.abc.log or filename.txt.bz2 . So is there any template of regex that can ```\b.bz2\b|\b.json\b```

Comment: To parse out any final `.thing` extension, you would use my last `fileparse()` example.

Comment: Yes I tried the ```fileparse()``` method. New to Perl didn't realize can utilize ```File::Basename``` module like this. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Would you please try the following:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

my @exts = qw / json bz2 log gz2 txt /;         # list of the possible extensions
my $pat = '\.(?:' . join("|", @exts) . ')$';    # regex to match the extension
my $str = "namefile.json.bz2";                  # provided example

1 while $str =~ s/$pat//o;                      # remove the extension as much as possible
print "$str\n";
```

Example of `$str`:

```
namefile.json.bz2
namefile.foo.txt
namefile.json.foo.bz2
```

Output:

```
namefile
namefile.foo
namefile.json.foo
```

As an option, you can create a file of extensions, read it from within the `perl` script, then generate the variable `@exts`.

Answer (score 0):

this will work as long as the filename is of type `namefile.ext` and `namefile.type.ext`

```
my $str = "namefile.json.bz2";

$str =~ s/(\.\w+)?\.\w+$//;

print $str;
```